# Selenium: unable to click on class and image

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm using Selenium web driver and trying to click on search image and its unable to click on this. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I have tried

xpath option

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2][@class='icon-button combo-button']")).click();
```

Also tried for image

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img[contains(@src,'iconActionSearch.png')]")).click();
```

I have tried exactly the same from Selenium IDE

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divToolbar']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img")).click();
```

this is where above code is suppose to act

```
   <td class="icon-button combo-button" title="Search">
    <img src="../common/images/iconActionSearch.png">
```

this is html snippet i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body class="navigator" onbeforeunload="closeAllChildWindows()" onload="initializeSlideIns()">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<div class="mmenu" style="display: none;">
<form name="navigatorForm">
<div id="pageHeadDiv">
<div class="toolbars">
<div class="toolbar-container">
<div id="divToolbar" class="toolbar-frame">
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="toolbar functions">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="icon-button" nowrap="" itemid="emx567127522162.935" title="Home">
<td class="icon-button combo-button" title="Search">
<img src="../common/images/iconActionSearch.png">
</td>
<td class="menu-arrow" title="Search">
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<script src="./scripts/emxBreadcrumbs.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="./scripts/emxQuery.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="pageContentDiv" style="top: 62px;">
<div id="layerOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="panelSlideIn" class="dialog viewer" style="top: 62px; display: none;">
<div id="windowshadeMask" style="z-index: 50; display: none;">
</form>
<div id="checkoutdiv">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

try using css selectors alternative:

```
String cssSelector="td[class='icon-button combo-button']>img"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).click();
```

a piece of advice: use firebug, firefox extension to verify you located element properly
[image]

Comment: thanks Eugene for your answer, infact it still does not work. what i understand that webelement is existing because there is no NoSuchElementException exception but not sure why it is not clickable.

Comment: NoSuchElementException appears in two cases: either you found locator of the element improperly. This problem gets resolved by verifying locator in firebug as I mentioned in my post. Other possible problem  - element is  not rendered  and you want to interact on non rendered element. Solution: try to use explicit or implicit wait mechanisms e.g.
driver.manage.timeout.implicitWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Thanks, you are right. it seems element where I was trying to click was not rendered correctly. implicit wait did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a different solution to eugene (which, by the way, is a better way of doing it since the CSS selector will be faster), if you must use XPath:

```
//td[@class='icon-button combo-button']/img
```

Your original XPath solutions will never work, they are very confined to specific positions. You put in an extra div somewhere and your entire XPath will fall over. So go for something that's a little less brittle.